# do I have odbc/jdbc and their drivers installed and configured by default?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc

I have got confused about odbc/jdbc concepts,I know what they mean and how they work,but I have some questions,it will be really kind of you to help me to get the answers.
I have used just sql server as db by now but never installed and configured odbc or its driver,what is this?do I have them installed and configured by default?
Is it always necessary to have odbc/jdbc and their drivers installed and configured ?
why should java have jdbc?why just it can't use odbc like other programming languages?
can I use for example c# and jdbc?

Comment: So many why in one question!!! :)

Comment: sorry,but they are all one type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have used just sql server as db by now but never installed and
>   configured odbc or its driver,what is this?

I thought you said you knew what ODBC was? Kind of sounds like you are not not sure?

An odbc driver is an open database driver connection which is a generic way to connect to most databases. It might work for basic functionality but it's typically best to get a more specific driver type for the database you're  using.

> do I have them installed and configured by default?

You usually have odbc drivers by default (I'm not sure what system you're on or even then how it was set up) but the connections are not configured. You can configure them as environment variables in Windows (if that's what you're using) or within your application as needed.

> Is it always necessary to have odbc/jdbc and their drivers installed
>   and configured ?

No. Only if you want to use an odbc/jdbc connection.

> why should java have jdbc?

It's the standard API for Java. Sorry I don't know what else to say about that.

> why just it can't use odbc like other programming languages?

Because the standard database API that was programmed for java is jdbc.

> can I use for example c# and jdbc?

Yes but are you specifically trying to connect to the SQL Server? I'd use something like SqlClient to do that (System.Data.SqlClient).

Comment: you mean when using a specific database such as sql server,we don't have to install and configure odbc?

Comment: It depends on what language/system you're developing in. ODBC is a method of connecting to a database. If the language you're using only supports odbc for connecting to a SQL Server database that's what you would use, if it has a well supported alternative, such as C# does -- use that.